How to fix Update in RFID TimeOut vb.net
So I'm Creating a HR Management System for our Project in our school with an Attendance Function that Inserts Time In and Updates Time Out. The Time In works it inserts the Data in the Table when I put SELECT * FROM attendance; the Data shows but when I try to tap the ID for Time Out the Debug Message I created shows. "Error: No records updated. Please check if the record exists with the matching Date, EmployeeID, and TimeIn." and "Error: No matching record found for the given Date, EmployeeID, and TimeIn. Please verify the data." I tried using ChatGPT 4 but nothing change it can't update the TimeOut and EmployeeTotalHour. Please help me fix my problem I've been dealing with this problem for a week now. Please Help me. I'll Put the Link Below.
This is where the RFID Tap goes:
Private Sub HandleRFIDTap(rfid As String)
    Try
        OpenConnection()
        Using transaction As NpgsqlTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction()
            If Not employeeSessions.ContainsKey(rfid) Then
                Dim employeeData = FetchEmployeeData(rfid)

                If employeeData IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim timeIn As DateTime = DateTime.Now
                    employeeData("TimeIn") = timeIn.ToString("hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                    employeeData("DateNow") = timeIn.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                    employeeSessions(rfid) = New Dictionary(Of String, String)(employeeData)

                    If Not AttendanceRecordExists(employeeData("EmployeeID"), timeIn) Then
                        InsertAttendanceRecord(employeeData, timeIn)
                        transaction.Commit()
                        ShowAttendancePopUp(employeeData)
                    Else
                        MsgBox("Attendance already recorded for today.")
                        transaction.Rollback()
                    End If
                Else
                    MsgBox("RFID not recognized or employee not found.")
                    System.Media.SystemSounds.Exclamation.Play()
                    transaction.Rollback()
                End If
            Else
                Dim sessionData = employeeSessions(rfid)

                If sessionData.ContainsKey("TimeIn") Then
                    Dim timeIn As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(sessionData("TimeIn"), "hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                    Dim timeOut As DateTime = DateTime.Now

                    If Not sessionData.ContainsKey("TimeOut") Then
                        Dim hoursWorked As TimeSpan = timeOut - timeIn
                        sessionData("TimeOut") = timeOut.ToString("hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                        sessionData("EmployeeTotalHour") = hoursWorked.TotalHours.ToString("F2")

                        If UpdateAttendanceRecord(sessionData, timeOut, hoursWorked) > 0 Then
                            transaction.Commit()
                            ShowAttendancePopUp(sessionData)
                            employeeSessions.Remove(rfid)
                        Else
                            MsgBox("Error: No records updated. Please check if the record exists with the matching Date, EmployeeID, and TimeIn.")
                            transaction.Rollback()
                        End If
                    Else
                        MsgBox("Error: TimeOut already recorded for this employee.")
                        transaction.Rollback()
                    End If
                Else
                    MsgBox("Error: No Time In found for this employee.")
                    transaction.Rollback()
                End If
            End If
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error: " & ex.Message)
    Finally
        CloseConnection()
    End Try
End Sub

This is where Insert happens in Attendance:
Private Sub InsertAttendanceRecord(employeeData As Dictionary(Of String, String), timeIn As DateTime)
    Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO attendance (""Date"", ""TimeIn"", ""EmployeeID"", ""EmployeeName"", ""EmployeePosition"", ""EmployeeDaySchedule"") " &
                          "VALUES (@Date, @TimeIn, @EmployeeID, @EmployeeName, @EmployeePosition, @EmployeeDaySchedule)"
    Try
        Using cmd As New NpgsqlCommand(query, conn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", timeIn.Date)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeIn", timeIn.TimeOfDay)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", employeeData("EmployeeID"))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeName", employeeData("EmployeeName"))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeePosition", employeeData("EmployeePosition"))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeDaySchedule", employeeData("EmployeeDaySchedule"))
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error inserting attendance record: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

This is Where Update Happens:
Private Function UpdateAttendanceRecord(sessionData As Dictionary(Of String, String), timeOut As DateTime, hoursWorked As TimeSpan) As Integer
    Dim rowsAffected As Integer = 0
    Dim updateQuery As String = "UPDATE attendance SET ""TimeOut"" = @TimeOut, ""EmployeeTotalHour"" = @TotalHour " &
                            "WHERE ""Date"" = @Date AND ""EmployeeID"" = @EmployeeID AND ""TimeIn"" = @TimeIn"

    Using updateCmd As New NpgsqlCommand(updateQuery, conn)
        updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeOut", timeOut.TimeOfDay)
        updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalHour", hoursWorked.TotalHours.ToString("F2"))

        Dim dateValue As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(sessionData("DateNow"), "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dateValue)

        updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", sessionData("EmployeeID"))
        updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeIn", DateTime.ParseExact(sessionData("TimeIn"), "hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay)

        rowsAffected = updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using

    If rowsAffected = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Error: No matching record found for the given Date, EmployeeID, and TimeIn. Please verify the data.")
    End If

    Return rowsAffected
End Function

I tried tapping it 1 time SUCCESS! the data is inserted but after tapping it the 2nd time the error occurs and cannot update the TimeOut. I was thinking of making a separate form for the TimeOut but our professor expect us to have 1 form only that records the Time In and Time Out. Here is my Full Code.
Full Code:
Imports Npgsql
Imports System.Globalization

Public Class Attendance
    Private Timer As New Timer()
    Private PopUp As AttendancePopUp
    Private employeeSessions As New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String))()

    Public Sub Attendance_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        RFIDTxt.Focus()
    End Sub

    Public Sub RFIDTxt_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles RFIDTxt.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            Dim tappedRFID As String = RFIDTxt.Text.Trim()
            If tappedRFID.Length > 0 Then
                Try
                    HandleRFIDTap(tappedRFID)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox("Error: " & ex.Message)
                End Try
                RFIDTxt.Clear()
            End If
            e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub HandleRFIDTap(rfid As String)
        Try
            OpenConnection()
            Using transaction As NpgsqlTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction()
                If Not employeeSessions.ContainsKey(rfid) Then
                    Dim employeeData = FetchEmployeeData(rfid)

                    If employeeData IsNot Nothing Then
                        Dim timeIn As DateTime = DateTime.Now
                        employeeData("TimeIn") = timeIn.ToString("hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                        employeeData("DateNow") = timeIn.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                        employeeSessions(rfid) = New Dictionary(Of String, String)(employeeData)

                        If Not AttendanceRecordExists(employeeData("EmployeeID"), timeIn) Then
                            InsertAttendanceRecord(employeeData, timeIn)
                            transaction.Commit()
                            ShowAttendancePopUp(employeeData)
                        Else
                            MsgBox("Attendance already recorded for today.")
                            transaction.Rollback()
                        End If
                    Else
                        MsgBox("RFID not recognized or employee not found.")
                        System.Media.SystemSounds.Exclamation.Play()
                        transaction.Rollback()
                    End If
                Else
                    Dim sessionData = employeeSessions(rfid)

                    If sessionData.ContainsKey("TimeIn") Then
                        Dim timeIn As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(sessionData("TimeIn"), "hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                        Dim timeOut As DateTime = DateTime.Now

                        If Not sessionData.ContainsKey("TimeOut") Then
                            Dim hoursWorked As TimeSpan = timeOut - timeIn
                            sessionData("TimeOut") = timeOut.ToString("hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                            sessionData("EmployeeTotalHour") = hoursWorked.TotalHours.ToString("F2")

                            If UpdateAttendanceRecord(sessionData, timeOut, hoursWorked) > 0 Then
                                transaction.Commit()
                                ShowAttendancePopUp(sessionData)
                                employeeSessions.Remove(rfid)
                            Else
                                MsgBox("Error: No records updated. Please check if the record exists with the matching Date, EmployeeID, and TimeIn.")
                                transaction.Rollback()
                            End If
                        Else
                            MsgBox("Error: TimeOut already recorded for this employee.")
                            transaction.Rollback()
                        End If
                    Else
                        MsgBox("Error: No Time In found for this employee.")
                        transaction.Rollback()
                    End If
                End If
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error: " & ex.Message)
        Finally
            CloseConnection()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Function AttendanceRecordExists(employeeID As String, dateValue As DateTime) As Boolean
        Dim exists As Boolean = False
        Dim query As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM attendance WHERE ""Date"" = @Date AND ""EmployeeID"" = @EmployeeID"
        Using cmd As New NpgsqlCommand(query, conn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dateValue.Date)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", employeeID)
            exists = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) > 0
        End Using
        Return exists
    End Function

    Private Function FetchEmployeeData(rfid As String) As Dictionary(Of String, String)
        Dim employeeData As Dictionary(Of String, String) = Nothing

        Dim query As String = "SELECT ""EmployeeID"", ""EmployeeName"", ""EmployeePosition"", ""EmployeeDaySchedule"" FROM employee WHERE id = @ID"
        Using cmd As New NpgsqlCommand(query, conn)
            Select Case rfid
                Case "2091286169" : cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", 1)
                Case "2085555385" : cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", 2)
                Case "2092396169" : cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", 3)
                Case Else
                    Return Nothing
            End Select

            Dim reader As NpgsqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            If reader.Read() Then
                employeeData = New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {
                    {"EmployeeID", reader("EmployeeID").ToString()},
                    {"EmployeeName", reader("EmployeeName").ToString()},
                    {"EmployeePosition", reader("EmployeePosition").ToString()},
                    {"EmployeeDaySchedule", reader("EmployeeDaySchedule").ToString()}
                }
            End If
            reader.Close()
        End Using

        Return employeeData
    End Function

    Private Sub InsertAttendanceRecord(employeeData As Dictionary(Of String, String), timeIn As DateTime)
        Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO attendance (""Date"", ""TimeIn"", ""EmployeeID"", ""EmployeeName"", ""EmployeePosition"", ""EmployeeDaySchedule"") " &
                              "VALUES (@Date, @TimeIn, @EmployeeID, @EmployeeName, @EmployeePosition, @EmployeeDaySchedule)"
        Try
            Using cmd As New NpgsqlCommand(query, conn)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", timeIn.Date)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeIn", timeIn.TimeOfDay)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", employeeData("EmployeeID"))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeName", employeeData("EmployeeName"))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeePosition", employeeData("EmployeePosition"))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeDaySchedule", employeeData("EmployeeDaySchedule"))
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error inserting attendance record: " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Function UpdateAttendanceRecord(sessionData As Dictionary(Of String, String), timeOut As DateTime, hoursWorked As TimeSpan) As Integer
        Dim rowsAffected As Integer = 0
        Dim updateQuery As String = "UPDATE attendance SET ""TimeOut"" = @TimeOut, ""EmployeeTotalHour"" = @TotalHour " &
                                "WHERE ""Date"" = @Date AND ""EmployeeID"" = @EmployeeID AND ""TimeIn"" = @TimeIn"

        Using updateCmd As New NpgsqlCommand(updateQuery, conn)
            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeOut", timeOut.TimeOfDay)
            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalHour", hoursWorked.TotalHours.ToString("F2"))

            Dim dateValue As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(sessionData("DateNow"), "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dateValue)

            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", sessionData("EmployeeID"))
            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeIn", DateTime.ParseExact(sessionData("TimeIn"), "hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay)

            rowsAffected = updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using

        If rowsAffected = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Error: No matching record found for the given Date, EmployeeID, and TimeIn. Please verify the data.")
        End If

        Return rowsAffected
    End Function

    Private Sub ShowAttendancePopUp(employeeData As Dictionary(Of String, String))
        PopUp = New AttendancePopUp()
        PopUp.SetEmployeeData(employeeData)
        PopUp.Show()
        PopUp.AttendancePanel.Select()

        Timer.Interval = 5000
        AddHandler Timer.Tick, AddressOf ClosePopUp
        Timer.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ClosePopUp(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Timer.Stop()
        Timer.Dispose()
        If PopUp IsNot Nothing Then
            PopUp.Hide()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ShutdownBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ShutdownBtn.Click
        Dim Welcome As New Welcome()
        CType(Me.MdiParent, MDIParent).LoadFormInMDI(Welcome)
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

End Class


This is generally an issue with a transaction not being committed and subsequent transactions/sessions not seeing the results from the preceding transaction/session. Assuming the Postgres logging is set to at least log_statement='mod' then look at the log and see if you are committing correctly.
